# Button is glitching and I have to click twice to reveal information, and the photos are not aligning properly, why is this?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button that hides information and reveals information. All of the content is in the  tag. There are two issues with this code.

```
1. You have to click the button twice to reveal information. 
2. When information is revealed the pictures don't align like it should.. it gets moved to the middle then the right.
```

How can I fix these issues..?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle").text();
    if (elem == "More News >") {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
      $("#toggle").text("Read Less");
      $("#text").slideDown();
     } else {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
      $("#toggle").text("More News >");
      $("#text").slideUp();
     }
    });
    });
```

```css
#text{
       display:none;
        }

    .btn-container{
      margin: auto;
      height:44px;
      width:166.23px;
  
       }

        button{
        user-select:none;
       -webkit-user-select:none;
        -moz-user-select:none;
        -ms-user-select:none;
       cursor:pointer;
        border: solid 1px;
         padding:8px;
        font-size:1em;
       background: transparent;
       color:black;
        box-sizing:border-box;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2  style = "text-align:center;" > All Stories</h2>
    
      <hr> </hr> 
       <div class="smallSpacer">


      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
           <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>

          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
            <img src = "/images/news1.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
           </div>
     </div>

      <hr> </hr> 

      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
           <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>

          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
            <img src = "/images/news2.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
           </div>
     </div>

     <hr> </hr> 

      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
           <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>

          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
            <img src = "/images/news3.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
           </div>
     </div>

     <hr> </hr> 
     <div class="smallSpacer">


      <div>
        <br>
        <span id="text">

        <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
           <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>

          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
            <img src = "/images/news2.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
           </div>
     </div>

     <hr> </hr> 

      <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align:left;"> 
          <p class="#"  style = "color:lightgray;  ">Jan, 01, 2019 </p>
           <small>Title of the news article will be diplayed under the photo. </small>
        </div>

          <div class ="col-sm-6" style = "text-align: right;">
            <img src = "/images/news3.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:300px; ">
           </div>
     </div> <br>

      </div>
      <div class="btn-container">
        <button id="toggle"> More News > </button>
      </div>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

      <div class="bigSpacer"></div>
      </span>

       </section>
```

Expected: Button should reveal information smoothly with one click, and images should align to the right.

Actual: There is a glitch and you have to click twice to reveal information, and images get aligned to the right after they go to the centre of the page first.

Comment: Hi @tsharma , do you have a JSFiddle/codepen/etc of your project?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your first click isn't registering is probably because the exact text in your html `<button id="toggle"> More News > </button>` is different then your jquery code `$("#toggle").text("More News >");` Therefore the first time when you click, the else statement is triggered assigning "More News >" to the button, then it toggles there after.

To fix this, you might want to add an attribute to your toggler button

```
<button id="toggle" toggle="expand">More News ></button>
```

and then use the following:

```
if($("#toggle").attr("toggle") === "expand") {
  $("#text").css("display", "inline");
  $("#toggle").attr("toggle", "shrink");
}
```

Comment: I added that to the main.js file code, when I click the button it works fine. The button works with one click and the images align properly. But, then the More News Button appears again and if I click it it changes to Read Less, and the entire thing glitches again and the photos don't get aligned properly.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle").text();
    if (elem == "More News >") {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
      $("#toggle").text("Read Less");
      $("#text").slideDown();
    } else {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
      $("#toggle").text("More News >");
      $("#text").slideUp();
    }
    if($("#toggle").attr("toggle") === "expand") {
  $("#text").css("display", "inline");
  $("#toggle").attr("toggle", "shrink");
}
  });
});

Comment: this is what I added, its this what you meant!

Comment: You need to add a else statement there. Otherwise it will not text the other case. `else { $("#text").css("display", "none"); $("#toggle").attr("toggle", "expand"); }`

Comment: Now the button is inactive, and the text does not appear or hide.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle").text();
    if (elem == "More News >") {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
      $("#toggle").text("Read Less");
      $("#text").slideDown();
    } else {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
      $("#toggle").text("More News >");
      $("#text").slideUp();
    }
    if($("#toggle").attr("toggle") === "expand") {
  else { $("#text").css("display", "none");
  $("#toggle").attr("toggle", "expand");
}
  };